# how to find out if the value in my multiline textbox which can accept HTML tags has a href tag i.e <a href=> </a> tag

Tags: .net, html, href, multiline

I have a multiline Textbox that can accept HTML Tags.
But links are not allowed as part of the HTML tags that the user can input. 
In other words no href tags can be included as values in this textbox. 
I need to validate for this. 
How do I go about doing this? 
I am new to .net and so I dont know how to achieve this. 
Please help.

Updated this. I created a asp regularExpression Validator. but it is giving me syntax error.
What am I doing wrong? I am new to .net and Regex. please help.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="EmailLinkValidator" runat="server" controltovalidate="EmailTextBox" display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="(?m:(?:<a )?href|</a>\r?\n?)" cssclass="clsError" errormessage="<%=this.ERR_MSG%>">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: See the [Sanitize](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/HtmlUtilities.cs) method.

Comment: So do I only need to implement the Sanitize method only for _whitelist_a  if I want to remove only the <a href tag?

Comment: Before starting to remove the `a`s see my comment under Teddy's answer and read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#HTML-script_injection_.28cross-site_scripting.29

Comment: Yes. I think so. Please see below comment.

Comment: You can also try [WikiPlex](http://wikiplex.codeplex.com/). instead of taking html input from user you can use wiki syntax. You would be safe while getting the formatted input from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use regular expression to test if the text contains "A" tag

```
    string text = "<div class='answer-help'><p> <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer'>tips</a></p></div>";
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex ex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<a .*>.*</a>");
    bool containsATag = ex.IsMatch(text);
```

Then it will return a true

Comment: Would your regex catch this? `<script>document.write( unescape( '%3Ca%20href%3D%27http%3A//google.com%27%3EClick%3C/a%3E' ) );</script>` :)

Comment: I am new to .net. But supposedly Yes as I am sanitizing the HTML tags before saving. So no scripts are allowed. But I should not be saving any HREF tags specifically and should give an alert to the user in this case. Hence wanted to check that specifically.

Comment: Please help.. I am still stuck.

Comment: @Teddy - I updated my Regular Expression Validator. But it is giving me syntax error. Can you please help. Thanks

Comment: @Ditty I think the regExp "(?m:(?:<a )?href|</a>\r?\n?)" is not in correct syntax. I'm not sure what you mean by "(?", "m:" and ")?"